# Crown area calculation with lidR::.stdmetrics differs from raster::area

Tags: lidar, lidr, convex-hull, concave-hull

I found out that tree crowns delineation using `lidR::.stdmetrics` calculates an area that is different from the area calculated by `raster::area()` or QGIS with the field calculator `$area` function.
The versions I am using are: `lidR 3.1.1`, `raster 3.4-5` and `QGIS 3.4.8-Madeira`.

Also, the area calculated with `lidR` is the same whether you indicate `concave` or `convex` for the type of hull. Shouldn't it be different?

[image: Same tree crown delineated by convex type (red) and concave type (blue)]

I found this out with my own data but it can be checked too following the wikis from the github page for Segment individual trees and compute metrics 1 and 2 from  [here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki).

```
require(lidR)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)

hulls_concave  <- delineate_crowns(las, type = "concave", concavity = 2, func = .stdmetrics)
hulls_convex  <- delineate_crowns(las, , type = "convex", func = lidR::.stdmetrics)

hulls_concave$area2_conc <- raster::area(hulls_concave)
hulls_convex$area2_conv <- raster::area(hulls_convex)

df <- data.frame(hulls_concave$area, hulls_concave$area2_conc, 
                 hulls_convex$area, hulls_convex$area2_conv)

head(df)
#>   hulls_concave.area hulls_concave.area2_conc hulls_convex.area hulls_convex.area2_conv
#> 1             8.3148                 5.411255            8.3148                6.810303
#> 2            11.3176                 6.076416           11.3176                7.972168
#> 3            39.5720                13.700073           39.5720               21.715088
#> 4            17.7599                 9.352905           17.7599               12.575073
#> 5            34.3893                20.950684           34.3893               26.436523
#> 6            16.7090                 5.991821           16.7090               10.282349
```

Which is the reason that `lidR::.stdmetrics` calculates the same area for `convex` and `concave` hulls and that this area is different from the one calculated by `raster::area()` or QGIS `$area` function?

**EDIT:** I actually found that by using `lidR::.stdtreemetrics` instead of `lidR::.stdmetrics` it gives back the same area as `raster::area()` and also that both areas for `concave` and `convex` hulls are different. What is the difference between `lidR::.stdtreemetrics` and `lidR::.stdmetrics` for segmenting tree crowns?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, then the Area that we get from using .stmetrics in Cloud_metrics is the area of the minimal square|rectangle that contains all the points of the .las file, right ? So for example, let's say we are working with circular las files of 15 meter of radius. Then, on average, the Area is supposed to be contained between 0m² and 900m², but in optimal conditions, most often close to 880m²-900m². Is that right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdmetrics` is the combination of `stdmetrics_ctrl` + `stdmetrics_z` + `stdmetrics_i` + `stdmetrics_rn`. The `area` you get comes from `stdmetrics_ctrl` which computes the area of the bounding box of the processed points. This is described [here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/stdmetrics). This originally intended to check if your pixels were fully populated after `grid_metrics`. For example pixels on the edges of the tiles or on the edges of a lake may be incomplete. In the following, pixels are expected to be ~400 m² but some are not fully populated.

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Topography.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
m <- grid_metrics(las, .stdmetrics_ctrl)
plot(m$area)
```

[image]

When the level of regularization for metrics computation is not the pixel the metrics are still computable but not necessarily relevant. Later in the development of `lidR` the function `tree_metrics()` and `delineate_crown()` were added with the same capability of computing metrics. But for theses functions, standards raster-based metrics are not necessarily relevant (the opposite is also true). So `stdtreemetrics()` was added to easily get some interesting tree-based metrics. In this case the area is the one you are expecting.

Now you can also use `stdmetrics_z` or `stdmetrics_i` on a tree-based level.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. Now I was wondering if there is a way to combine ```stdtreemetrics``` + ```stdmetrics_z``` so the tree crowns also get the standard metrics like Hmean, Hsd, Hkurt... I guess that one way is to create a new function but maybe there is another way to indicate this

Comment: Sure, read the doc and examples of `?stdmetrics` and/or ask a new question